# The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Project` instance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i'm trying to work with django-rest-framework and serializers ,and i keep getting this error :

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 
  `recruitment_date` on serializer `EmployeeSerializer`.
  The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 
  `Project` instance.
  Original exception text was: 'Project' object has no attribute 'recruitment_date'

models.py :

```
class Employee(models.Model):

    f_name           = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    l_name           = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    telephone        = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='')
    recruitment_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    salary           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.f_name +' '+self.l_name



class Project(models.Model):


    name             = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    statuts          = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices = STATUS,default= STATUS[0])
    description      = models.TextField(blank=True)
    leader           = models.OneToOneField(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name = 'leader')
    p_employees      = models.ManyToManyField(Employee)
    estimated_budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=4)
    start_date       = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    end_date         = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    tasks            = models.ManyToManyField(Task)
    materials        = models.ManyToManyField(Materials)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py :

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields=['id','f_name','l_name','telephone','recruitment_date','salary']



class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    leader = EmployeeSerializer()
    p_employees = EmployeeSerializer(many =True)
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many =True)
    materials = MaterialsSerializer(many =True)

    class Meta :

        model = Project
        fields = ['name','statuts','description','leader','p_employees',
        'start_date','end_date','tasks','materials']
```

Answer (score 0):

That `recruitment_date` attribute/column might not actually exist in your Django database. Sure it's in your model, but did you make migrations then migrate?

Try running your development server and see if a message that says "Your models have changed" or something along those lines. Django is pretty good when it comes to those things.

If anything, I highly recommend you just makemigrations and migrate. It won't hurt.

**Then**

If the database already has that column/attribute, then just do this with your serializer. It's the best "good enough" solution I can do:

```
class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = '__all__'
```